# Editable Jupyter pandas table (paged, multi-row selection, checkboxes)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, datagrid

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=
    'id  title             ok   '.split(), data=[
    #----------------------------
    [1, 'Lorem ipsum',     True ],
    [2, 'dolor sit amet',  None ],
    [3, 'consectetur',     False],
    [4, 'adipiscing elit', None ],
    [5, 'Nullam',          False],
    [6, 'elementum',       True ],
    ]).set_index('id', drop=True)
```

It has ~200K rows, from which I select a subset with `df.loc[condition, :]`.

In Jupyter, I need to display the resulting subset as a *paged* editable table, in order to change some boolean values from None, to False, to True (it would be nice to have them displayed as checkboxes, grayed out if None; if three-state checkboxes are not possible, then two-state is OK, I will make two columns).

**Important:** I need to be able to select multiple rows (click the first row + Shift-click the last row) to set the boolean in batches, maybe the whole page at once.

The changes should propagate instantly to the underlying DataFrame (the big one).

The purpose of all this is to apply some weak labelling heuristics based on regular expressions (`df.title.str.contains(r'regexp')`).

I tried some solutions, but I couldn't find one with the multi-row selection feature. Do you know a widget/extension/package/something that has this feature out of the box (or easily added with a few lines of code)? Some packages are old/unmaintained and ask me to downgrade a lot of stuff, some offer way more than I need (fancy graphing, pivoting, grouping etc.)... but so far I was unable to find a simple, straight forward solution.

Also, I'm willing to try something outside of Jupyter, if there exists.

Thank you for any advice.